# Where does the Linux kernel reside in memory ?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

From some book I have, I have in my notes that the Linux kernel resides at `0xc00000000` on 32-bit systems, and is mapped into user space for performance reasons.

Is this accurate ? How can I verify this ?

Also, where does the kernel reside on 64-bit systems? Is it still at `0xc00000000`, or somewhere else ?

Comment: This might help: http://users.nccs.gov/~fwang2/linux/lk_addressing.txt

Comment: I read somewhere that OS:s in general are placed low in memory, and this has to do with the placement of the interrupt vector.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg, Where the interrupt vector is doesn't really matter.

Comment: @vonbrand: No, I agree... I'll find the source for that and be back at you, would be interesting to know. Perhaps for historical reasons, when memory access wasn't "random"?

Answer (score 2):

### Physical memory

In physical memory the kernel usually resides at a random offset above `0x1000000`. This depends on the kernel configuration options `CONFIG_PHYSICAL_START`, `CONFIG_PHYSICAL_ALIGN` and `CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE` and the kernel command line options `kaslr`/`nokaslr` as described in [the linux-insides book](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Booting/linux-bootstrap-6.html).

### Virtual memory (32-bit)

On 32-bit architectures the virtual address space split depends on the kernel configuration option [`CONFIG_PAGE_OFFSET`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/PAGE_OFFSET.html) which is on many architectures set implicitly by the `CONFIG_VMSPLIT_*` options. The configuration for your kernel is usually put alongside the kernel image into `/boot/config-<version>`, so you can check for the offset where the kernel area in virtual memory begins with `grep PAGE_OFFSET "/boot/config-$(uname -r)"`. The usual configuration for x86 is `CONFIG_VMSPLIT_3G` which sets the `PAGE_OFFSET` to 0xC0000000, reserving the upper 1 GiB of the address space for the kernel. For performance reasons this mapping is kept the same in all virtual address spaces, including all userspace processes.

The exact address where the kernel code starts is somewhere in this area and may be randomized on boot. That depends on the same configuration and kernel command line settings as the physical address randomization.

### Virtual memory (64-bit)

On 64-bit architectures the situation is different because of the vastly larger address space.

The details are architecture-dependent but the kernel resides at a memory range at the top of the address space by convention.

#### x86-64

On x86-64 (a.k.a. AMD64) the memory layout is [documented quite well](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt). There are two possible configurations depending on the hardware support and the configuration option `CONFIG_X86_5LEVEL`:

| Start (4-level paging) | Size (4-level p.) | Start (5-level paging) | Size (5-level p.) | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `0xFFFF800000000000` | 8 TiB | `0xFF00000000000000` | 4 PiB | guard hole, also reserved for hypervisor |
| `0xFFFF880000000000` | 0.5 TiB | `0xFF10000000000000` | 0.25 PiB | LDT remap for PTI |
| `0xFFFF888000000000` | 64 TiB | `0xFF11000000000000` | 32 PiB | direct mapping of all physical memory |
| `0xFFFFC90000000000` | 32 TB | `0xFFA0000000000000` | 12.5 PiB | vmalloc/ioremap space |
| `0xFFFFEA0000000000` | 1 TB | `0xFFD4000000000000` | 0.5 PiB | virtual memory map |
| `0xFFFFEC0000000000` | 16 TB | `0xFFDF000000000000` | 8 PiB | KASAN shadow memory |
|  |  |  |  | *idential layout from here on* |
| `0xFFFFFE0000000000` | 0.5 TB |  |  | cpu_entry_area mapping |
| `0xFFFFFF0000000000` | 0.5 TB |  |  | %esp fixup stacks |
| `0xFFFFFFEF00000000` | 64 GB |  |  | EFI region mapping space |
| `0xFFFFFFFF80000000` | 512 MB |  |  | **kernel text mapping**, mapped to physical address 0 |
| `0xFFFFFFFFA0000000` | 1520 MB |  |  | module mapping space |
| `FIXADDR_START` | ~0.5 MB |  |  | kernel-internal fixmap range, variable size and offset |
| `0xFFFFFFFFFF600000` | 4 kB |  |  | legacy vsyscall ABI |

So, the kernel area starts either at `0xFFFF800000000000` or `0xFF00000000000000` and the kernel code resides (usually at a randomized offset) in the area starting at `0xFFFFFFFF80000000`.

#### ARM64

On 64-bit ARM the [memory layout is somewhat similar to the layout on x86-64](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm64/memory.txt). The exact split depends on the kernel configuration (4kB/64kB pages, 2/3/4-level paging):

| Page size | Paging levels | kernel area starting address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 kB | 3 | `0xFFFFFF8000000000` |
| 4 kB | 4 | `0xFFFF000000000000` |
| 64 kB | 2 | `0xFFFFFC0000000000` |
| 64 kB | 3 | `0xFFFF000000000000` |

Answer (score 0):

Right now it resides at a semi random location thanks to aslr (assuming you have that compiled in and with a 64 bit system there's no reason not to and since it's 2016 you should be running a 64 bit system.... if you are low on memory just run a 64 bit kernel + 32 bit userland)

Comment: You seem to imply aslr is dependent upon a 64-bit architecture, which is incorrect. Wrt running a 64-bit system, _"should"_ is a bit strong, too - there are plenty of 32-bit SoCs available, or stocked up by manufacturers of long-lived programs. This isn't the Ubuntu SE. (Commenting in 2020 because it floated up to the top of the questions list for some reason this morning.)